# multiple bootable iso on usb flash drive

Tags: usb, iso, bootable

I have a 128gb usb flash drive on which I want to put bootable ISOs.

Windows 7, 8, 10 install discs and also partedmagic live ISO

I'd like to have a menu from which to choose which ISO image I want to load once I boot from the USB drive.

I found the following application http://www.pendrivelinux.com/xboot-multiboot-iso-usb-creator/

It seems to fit my needs, but I was wondering if people on here had recommendations for such a program.

Thanks

Comment: Anyone ? Still looking for this...

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind installing a Linux system on your flashdrive you can do this rather easily using the grml-rescueboot package. I used Lubuntu for it's small size and flexiblitly, installed the grml rescueboot package and dropped the ISO's I wanted to boot in the /boot/grml folder and ran `sudo update-grub` grml-rescueboot adds scripts to generate the menu and the necessary boot entries for all your ISO's. I haven't tested it with Windows Installation ISO's but I've had success with several and it's well worth trying. There's also a Grub Customizer package that you can use to dress up your menu among other things.

More info: https://askubuntu.com/questions/365248/adding-grub2-menu-entry-for-iso-using-grml-rescueboot/814626#814626

Answer (score 2):

"[MultiBootUSB](http://multibootusb.org/) is a cross platform software written in python which allows you to install multiple live linux on a USB disk non destructively and option to uninstall distros."

Works well.

Answer (score 1):

Though this is not a software recommendation, but - [IODD](http://iodd.kr/wordpress/product/iodd-2541/) hosts a lot of ISO images, bootable or not. Some models support also multiple "virtual disks".

(Older USB2.0 models a.k.a. "[Zalman Virtual CD emulator](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?field-keywords=iodd)")

Answer (score 1):

You could use YUMI, it creates a good menu and places entrys for each Iso loaded!
You can get it here for windows:

[YUMI multiboot pendrive](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/)

It really works great with Linux distros and various rescue discs, so it should work with Windows OS'es too.

Answer (score 0):

[Ventoy](https://www.ventoy.net/en/index.html) allows selecting from multiple .ISOs on the USB key and also searching the detected hard disk partitions.

You can select which .ISO you wish to boot from - just add and remove the .ISO files as you wish :)